# Duplicate elimination by group and condition not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I have col2 that contains values A, B, C, or D and col3 that has newer and older dates.

I can isolate with below duplicates found in col1 based on filtering for only A in col2 using `group_by` and `slice_head` but,

What I am trying to do is remove the duplicates based on below filter but (remove dupes based on col1 with col2 only in 'A'), and retain the row `slice(n = 1)` that represents the most recent date from col3 and still retain all of A,B,C,D in final output - leaving B,C,D untouched for duplicates etc. Instead I can only achieve keeping col2's A in my output and I lose B, C, D rows.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col3) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1 & col2 == 'A') %>% 
  arrange(desc(col1, col3)) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Raw Set

```
col1  col2 col3 (date)
11    A    older date
11    A    newer date
12    B    only 1 date
13    C    only 1 date
14    D    only 1 date
22    A    older date
22    B    newer date
```

Current output:

```
col1  col2  col3
11    A     Newer date
22    A     older date
```

Desired:

```
col1   col2 col3
11     A    Newer date
12     B    Only 1 date
13     C    Only 1 date
14     D    Only 1 date
22     A    Older Date
22     B    Newer Date
```

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 22L), col2 = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"), col3 = c("older date", "newer date", 
"only 1 date", "only 1 date", "only 1 date", "newer date", "older date"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: The 'col3' values are confusing when you say 'older date', 'newer date'.  Are those really Date values or just strings as showed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
   group_by(col1) %>% 
   filter(col2 != "A"|col2 == "A" & n() > 1) %>%
   group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
   slice_max(n = 1, order_by = col3) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   col1 col2  col3       
  <int> <chr> <chr>      
1    11 A     older date 
2    12 B     only 1 date
3    13 C     only 1 date
4    14 D     only 1 date
5    22 A     newer date 
6    22 B     older date
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 22L), col2 = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A"), col3 = c("older date", "newer date", 
"only 1 date", "only 1 date", "only 1 date", "newer date", "older date"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank so much for your response @akrun !

I am sorry - my example wasn't an exact representation of my situation. Please look at the edit - note, in raw set the final row - I can have a situation where I have 22 duplicate - but with A or B data - I still want to retain B. I think the `|` in the filter is going to mess me up - but I'm trying now. The main problem area are the first two rows - retain only A and newest date in rows 1/2 (discard older date row) AND keep all other data

Comment: @DreDay in your 'col3', is it actual dates or just stirng values as showed as the output will be affected by wheteher it is character or date class

Comment: I have them set up as dates but in `chr` type. All Columns are chr

Comment: @DreDay are those values '2022-01-05' etc or just 'older date', 'newer date' (i Updated the post assuming it is `Date` value like '2022-01-05'

Comment: Yes they're mdY date formats. It doesn't seem to quite work. In my set - it should be removing only 17 values where col1 is duplicated, A only filtered, and newest date -  but I end up eliminating hundreds with that. For row one I am trying to retain the newer date

Comment: @DreDay Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` that shows the issue